# How do I pronounce 疲れ

Tags: help

I'm learning Japanese from (glossika),
still very Beginner A1 Low (1.7%),
so I want to know how to pronounce 疲れ.

I know it's つかれ=tsu ka re,
but I hear it like (tu ka re),
and that the full Sentence,
疲れました.

Comment: If your native language is English or another Germanic language, it may be that your aspirated stop consonants have high stridency and that's why you hear Japanese /ts/ as _t_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'tsu' sound is mostly pronounced as 'tsu', not 'tu'. In the International Phonetic Alphabet, this is written as  [tsɯ] ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsu_(kana))).

- Description of how to make the sound: [http://www.coelang.tufs.ac.jp/ja/en/pmod/practical/#:~:text=The%20tsu%20(%E3%81%A4)%20is%20a,back%20of%20your%20lower%20teeth](http://www.coelang.tufs.ac.jp/ja/en/pmod/practical/#:%7E:text=The%20tsu%20(%E3%81%A4)%20is%20a,back%20of%20your%20lower%20teeth)
- Native speakers pronouncing 'tsu' - https://forvo.com/word/%E3%81%A4/#ja

Therefore, 疲れ is pronounced as 'tsukare' (つかれ).  Again, listen to the native speakers saying the word [here](https://forvo.com/word/%E7%96%B2%E3%82%8C/#ja).

In some Japanese dialects, there is a slight devoicing of some 'tsu' sounds, which might make it sound like 'tu'. For example, Wikipedia lists the case of 'kutsu' being pronounced 'kutu' (described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_phonology#Devoicing)), but I don't think this is common for the word 疲れ. Having said that, in the second example from Forvo above, the male voice does sound a little like 'tu'.

Comment: thank you so much!